# Codeigniter: won't load controller page

Tags: codeigniter

I have a web page made with codeigniter, and everything works fine, but when I try to add another controller it gives me a:"404 Page Not Found" - "The page you requested was not found." Why? The controller  i'm adding is the one from the tutorial (I'm practising):

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm using Ubuntu, if it makes any difference.

Comment: what is your controller file name? and check file permission

Comment: Did you set the default controller?

Comment: File name should be same as controller class but in simple letters

Comment: What is the name of php file in whch you have saved this controller ? And how do you call the controller ?

Comment: Thanks, that was it, my file name was with different name than the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better check this out

```
// FILE NAME : blog.php
 class Blog extends CI_Controller(){
       function Blog(){
           parent::__construct();
       }
       function index(){
           echo 'Helloworld';
       }
    }
```

1. Your controller filename should equal or same to your created class controller name.
2. try to put a constructor before your index like this.

Comment: I don't know why this was accepted as the answer, since it has two completely wrong things in it: `extends CI_Controller()` - what's with the parantheses? `function Blog()` this is a PHP 4 style constructor that should *not* be used anymore.

Comment: i agree that my post shouldn`t be accepted as answer if it doesnt solve the problem or give hints in creating a perfect solution for a problem